# Incremental backup of an iPhoto 09 library

Tags: macos, backup, iphoto

I want to backup my 40Gb iPhoto library to an external USB drive.  Due to the large size of the library, copying the whole thing each time is impractical.  As the external drive is rather small, I cannot use time machine.  Is there any easy way of doing of making an incremental backup or mirroring my home drive?  I am using OSX Version 10.6.2.

Answer (score 1):

Time Machine would be the first choice, I would think. You can browse Time Machine iPhoto backups from within iPhoto '09 itself (File menu).

[SuperDuper!](http://www.shirt-pocket.com/SuperDuper/SuperDuperDescription.html) or [Carbon Copy Cloner](http://www.bombich.com/) would work as well. You could back up your entire drive to the external *and* boot from it in the event of a disaster.

[image: It doesn't actually use the brushed metal look anymore]

[image: Carbon Copy Cloner]